# Hover a div and modify the CSS of another div using JS inside of the same row in a table with 3 rows using same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML table that includes 3 rows.
Each row has a column circle and a column panel (sometimes the panel column is before the circle, sometimes after).

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="panel-right></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="panel-left></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="circle"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="panel-right></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

When hover panel, panel goes left or right from 10px.

```
    table .panel-left:hover,
    table .panel-left:focus {
      margin-right: -10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    table .panel-right:hover,
    table .panel-right:focus {
      margin-left: -10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

With javascript, i want to modify the css of circle when hover the panel-left or panel right

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $(".panel-left").mouseover(function(){
        $(".circle").css("border", "5px solid #16a085");
      });

      $(".panel-left").mouseout(function(){
        $(".circle").css("border", "3px solid #cccccc");
      });

      $(".panel-right").mouseover(function(){
        $(".circle").css("border", "5px solid #16a085");
      });

      $(".panel-right").mouseout(function(){
        $(".circle").css("border", "3px solid #cccccc");
      });

    });
```

This is working well, except than all the circle are modified, when it should be only the circle inside of the row that contains the panel hovered.

What should be the javascript?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="circle-td">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="panel-right"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="panel-left"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="circle-td">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="circle-td">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="panel-right"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.circle, .panel-right, .panel-left {
   background-color:red;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
   border-radius:100%;
   border:3px solid #cccccc;
}

.panel-right, .panel-left {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:green;
}

.panel-left:hover,
.panel-left:focus {
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.panel-right:hover,
.panel-right:focus {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel-left, .panel-right').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).closest('td')
               .siblings('.circle-td')
               .find('.circle')
               .css('border', '5px solid #16a085');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).closest('td')
               .siblings('.circle-td')
               .find('.circle')
               .css('border', '5px solid #cccccc')
    });   
});
```

And here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz8ruhcp/6/)**

Comment: Thank you!

Except than it is when the user hover on then panel than the circle should be modified, otherwise it is a simple CSS hover modification

Comment: My apologies. The code and fiddle have been updated to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just tried it and that worked out perfectly!! You are a genius!!!